# Broken image links cant fix

Tags: reactjs, image

Cannot get the HTML path for images to work, tried ../public/images ../images /images /public/images Nothing seems to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Working CSS path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSVdg.png)

[Not working HTML path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSKgI.png)

[Site with broken footer imgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgksu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

in footer.js try:

```
<img src="../../public/images/BBB-Logo.jpg" alt="BBB" />
```

Comment: still broken :/
they were working before uploading to GH Pages. the screw up I think I had was that the folder for the images was originally named "Images" and the pathing called on "images"
instead of changing the path to "Images" to match the folder, I renamed the folder to "images" and then they broke in VS code.
Followed advice of deleting "Images" folder and making new "images" folder with the same images. The APP Background is the only one I could get to work again.

Comment: I closed everything down and re-opened (cause VS code dumb like that some times) I noticed that there is a second "Images" folder in the build folder that might be causing access confusion. Im going to try deleting that folder.

EDIT no change after removed redundant Image folder.